# MYSQL GROUP BY and WHERE indexes, with timestamp column

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by

I've implemented this query:

```
SELECT 
    evt.userId, evt.storeId, COUNT(1) AS totalVisits
FROM
    Event evt
WHERE
    evt.timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
    AND 
    evt.subtype = 2 
    AND 
    userID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY userId, storeId
HAVING totalVisits>16;
```

The Event table has millions of records. Column timestamp is DATETIME, and the other columns are INT. This table is accesed very often and have a lot of indexes.

At the beginning this query took more than 10 minutes to execute. I solve this by adding a new Index

```
ALTER TABLE Event 
    ADD INDEX `Event_timestamp_subtype_userId_storeId` (`timestamp` ASC, `subType` ASC, `userId` ASC, `storeId` ASC);
```

This works fine and I have results in less than 2 seconds.

The problem I have is when I change the condition INTERVAL 30 DAY. If I set INTERVAL 50 DAY (for example), MYSQL doesn't use the index I've created. Instead, it uses another index that only covers two columns.

The Explain Command:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT 
    evt.userId, evt.storeId, COUNT(1) AS totalVisits
FROM
    Event evt
WHERE
    evt.timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND NOW()
    AND 
    evt.subtype = 2 
    AND 
    evt.userID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY userId, storeId
HAVING totalVisits>16;
```

Explain OUTPUT:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                                                              | key                         | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | evt   | NULL       | ref  | Event_userId_index,Event_subType_storeId_index,Event_timetamp_index,Event_timestamp_subtype_userId_storeId | Event_subType_storeId_index | 3       | const | 7375964 |    25.00 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, if a put a 50 days condition the query is inviable. How can I make this query work with correct indexes independently of the value of the parameters?

I'm using mysql server 5.7.23

Thanks!

Regards

Comment: You might have more luck asking this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/
However, have you tried changing the order of the columns when defining your index? MySQL is probably deciding that your index is not selective enough because of the large number of timestamps in that range. If you put e.g. user_id or store_id first it might work better.

Comment: Personally, i'd try for an execution plan that avoids a "Using filesort" operation, with a covering index on `(subtype,userid,storeid,timestamp)`  (I might modify the query to `GROUP BY subtype,userid,storeid`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "lots of indexes".  A shotgun does not help.  Do you have *these* indexes, with the columns *in the given order*?

```
INDEX(subtype, timestamp)
INDEX(subtype, userID)
```

The optimizer might like to use either of those for the `WHERE`.  And, since it cannot consume all the `WHERE` (because of 2 ranges), it won't get to the columns in the `GROUP BY`.

The first column (`subtype`) is tested with `=`; this is easy.
The second column is a "range", so that is the last thing it can deal with.

A small improvement can be had by making each of those indexes into a "covering" index:

```
INDEX(subtype, timestamp, storeID, userID)
INDEX(subtype, userID, timestamp, storeID)
```

Now the processing need look only into the index's BTree, and not have to bounce between that BTree and the one with the data.

(The first 2 column are in a specific order; the other two can be swapped.)

If this is a 'huge' table (millions of rows), we can talk about another optimization since you effectively need a 2D index.

Comment: I solved the issue with a covering index ... but the order of fields is subtype,storeId,userId,timestamp. I tested other combinations but this one is the best. The query is running in less than 1 second, with no file sort or expensive operations. Thanks!